# Object leak using "retain"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, retaincount

I have a property defined with retain attribute which I am synthesizing:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISwitch *mySwitch;
```

And inside my loadView I am doing this:

```
self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
```

And finally inside my dealloc I am doing this:

```
self.mySwitch = nil;
```

Am I leaking this object (mySwitch) as I have used one alloc? Should I autorelease it while assigning it frame?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
self.mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
```

Actually calls retain *twice*- once for the `alloc` and again in the assignment to `self.mySwitch` (which is a property you've specified should `retain` any values assigned to it.) The fix I have been told is best is to add a call to `autorelease` on the line, making it:

```
self.mySwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are leaking. You are creating an owned object with `+alloc/-initWithFrame:`, then assigning that owned object to a property marked `retain`. This creates a second owned reference to the object. At this point, you leak your original owned reference, which causes the object itself to leak.

The correct behavior here is to call `-autorelease` on the object before assigning it to the property.

```
self.mySwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)] autorelease];
```

On a tangential note, it's not recommended that you access properties inside of `-dealloc`. The two reasons generally given for this are 1) this will broadcast KVO notifications, which you don't want inside of `-dealloc`, and 2) if anyone overrides the setter (in this class or a subclass) it may not behave properly. The recommended approach is to simply release the underlying ivar, so you'd see something like the following instead:

```
[mySwitch release];
```

Assigning nil to the property is perfectly safe (and recommended) everywhere else.

Comment: I see a value of nullifying certain properties in `-dealloc`. That way you can have a fine grained control over properties object deallocation sequence.  BTW you can minus me only once, but it doesn't negate the fact that you program with very dangerous assumptions.

Comment: Whether or not you use properties has absolutely no bearing on the order in which you release your ivars.

Comment: @Kevin Let me ask you, in which order your properties will be deallocated if you don't override `-dealloc`.  After you come up with an answer, imagine you have a situation in which property B would have a reference to property A. It would be plain dangerious to collect A before B, especially when these properties can be accessed from a different thread. Illegal memory access you get.

Comment: I didn't say don't override `dealloc`, nor did we talk about threading. You're just making up stuff now in an attempt to sound like you know what you're talking about. Oh, and if property B contains a reference to property A, that does not make collecting A before B dangerous, as B will still have an owned reference to A (therefore preventing A from deallocating). You clearly have absolutely no idea how manual memory management works.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't bring `-copy` into conversation.Your problem is that you absolutely incapable having civil conversation. Your argument #1) (about KVO)is laughable. I gave you my reasoning and I have -4, and somebody upvoted all your pseudo-science answers.  We must end it now. Good luck with your memory, you'll need it.

Comment: @bioffe – Kevin's right with both his arguments (although I don't agree with him about the `autorelease`). There are conventions and design patterns throughout Cocoa and this is just one of them. You're the one being aggressive in the comments. And since you're the one with the "custom memory model" you'll be the one in need of luck.

Comment: If you have `release` order dependencies in your `dealloc`'s implementation, *you are doing it wrong*.   If you have threading dependencies in your `dealloc` methods, **you are doing it seriously wrong**.

Comment: @bbum I don't have problems, Apple does often. Example would be MKMapView which you can collect before its pins falls down with animations. When pins animation ends, MKMapView is already a zombie. I fixed with a dealloc trick. I filled a bug it WAS accepted (again. Remember you were trying to convince me that NSDateFormatter was not leaking back in the days). It's very upsetting when a person such as yourself barge in without a context.

Comment: @bioffe I don't see how that is remotely relevant. No one claimed Apple's frameworks are perfect and *that* sounds like an ordering dependency of the type that I'm referring to.  If you have ordering dependencies in your dealloc method or, worse, threading dependencies, then you are doing it wrong (and, yes, there have been issues in the frameworks that boil down to that -- and, thru bug reports, they have been fixed).

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to autorelease, if you need a tighter memory management this should work for you:

```
UISwitch *myswitch_tmp= [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20)];
self.mySwitch = myswitch_tmp;
[myswitch_tmp release];
```

and later e.g. in dealloc

```
[mySwitch release];
```

Comment: +1 For being the only one to not take the cop out of using `autorelease`. There is a place for `autorelease`, such as when you can't control when an object will be retained (such as returning objects from methods), but that isn't the case here.

Comment: @Abizern: There is a reasonable case for using `release` instead of `autorelease`, but most of the time it will have zero measurable impact on the application while making the code slightly harder to read and increasing the risk of programmer error (namely, forgetting the `release` at the end). Also, while it's not very common, if your code can raise an exception, and the exception will be caught higher in the stack (e.g. it won't terminate the app), the `release` will be skipped and you will leak, but `autorelease` will work.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard - Had a chat IRL about this at NSCoderNight. That was the consensus. i.e. I'm just being picky and it's a premature optimisation. But so many answers on SO just seem to lay down a line of "this is how you do it" without touching on some of the related issues. Not using `autorelease` is an option. The choice of which option to use is up to the developer, but at least it's an informed choice rather than just parroting a way of writing code.

Answer (score -4):

Yes. You are leaking object. Remember one simple rule here:

if you used `+alloc` there is always must be corresponding `-release`.

Comment: Nope there isn't. There should be balanced retain and release count.

Comment: @Kevin Ballard I meant `-release`. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Max can you substantiate your statement?

Comment: Your rule is still far too simplistic. There are more ways to get an owned relationship than `+alloc`. A common acronym is NARC - this stands for `new`, `alloc`, `retain`, `copy` (or `mutableCopy`). If you call any of these methods, then you end up with an owned reference, and must call either `release` or `autorelease` to get rid of that owned reference.

Comment: @Kevin my rule says for each `+alloc`, you should have `-release` if you think otherwise, please provide your input. I didn't mean to write obj-c memory management guideline. Yes, you need `-release` for `-retain`, but it wasn't the question. Sheesh. My rule still works.

Comment: @Max So I guess you have nothing to add into this conversation. Good job in discouraging other forum members to share and help.

Comment: What do you want me to add? Kevin has already explained everything.

Comment: @Kevin. You are wrong. You assume that copy will be implemented in accordance to certain assumptions that it will return owned object. You can not guarantee that. Even Apple allow themselves such mistakes, see my post about NSDateFormatters. You are actually wrong and your suggestion will lead to a pathetic core dump.

Comment: @bioffe If I understand you correctly, you're saying that despite the extremely simple and clear memory management guidelines, one should always assume that other people's code will *not* follow these guidelines, and therefore one should... what, make up the rules as you go along? Once you assume that nobody else is following the guidelines, your only recourse is to never release anything for fear that it will crash, which leads to leaking every object ever created.

Comment: @Kevin. My rule is axiom that was inline with a question. You stated that I should never call `-dealoc` directly. That's another assumption you brought in here. if I develop my own custom memory model. It's perfectly acceptable. All I said that one should use `-dealoc` with every `-alloc` you made. I belive it's is very accurate and correct rule. I don't understand how come I get slammed by providing a correct answer?

Comment: @bioffe: Because it's simply not correct. The assumption here is that you're operating on an object that inherits from NSObject or NSProxy (if not, then this entire conversation is moot, because who knows what `dealloc` means on other objects?) Given that, calling `-dealloc` manually is absolutely incorrect. Even if you use a custom allocator, calling `-dealloc` is wrong.